# Can I specialize an variadic template template parameter with non template class?

Tags: c++, templates

I would like to specialize an template class with variadic template template parameter by non-template class. Please see below.

```
// non-template base class
class BaseNoneTemplate {
public:
    void print(void) {
        std::cout << "BaseNoneTemplate" << std::endl;
    }
};

// template base class
template <typename T>
class BaseTemplate {
public:
    void print(void) {
    std::cout << "BaseTemplate" << std::endl;
    }
};

// primary template class
template <template <typename...> class T_Self, typename... T_Params>
class VariadicTemplate : public T_Self<T_Params...> {
public:

    VariadicTemplate() = default;
    virtual ~VariadicTemplate() = default;

    void print(void) {
        this->T_Self<T_Params...>::print();
    }

};

// specialized class with a non-template class
// ********** This specialized class makes an error: see the error message at the end of this question ***********
template <>
class VariadicTemplate<BaseNoneTemplate> : public BaseNoneTemplate {
public:

    VariadicTemplate() = default;
    virtual ~VariadicTemplate() = default;

    void print(void) {
        this->BaseNoneTemplate::print();
    }

};

// specialized class with an template class
// ***** This class is an ok example *****
template <typename T_Value>
class VariadicTemplate<BaseTemplate, T_Value> : public BaseTemplate<T_Value> {
public:

    VariadicTemplate() = default;
    virtual ~VariadicTemplate() = default;

    void print(void) {
        this->BaseTemplate<T_Value>::print();
    }

};

void test_variadic_template(void) {
    VariadicTemplate<BaseNoneTemplate> non_template;
    VariadicTemplate<BaseTemplate, int> an_template;
    non_template.print();
    an_template.print();
}
```

In the code above, I could not specialize an template class with variadic template template parameter by non-template class, BaseNoneTemplate.
 Does someone knows how to specialize it with non-template class?

The error by compiler is following,

```
../template_template_variadic.hpp:44:40: error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for ‘template<template<class ...> class T_Self, class ... T_Params> class VariadicTemplate’ class VariadicTemplate<BaseNoneTemplate> : public BaseNoneTemplate {
                                    ^
../template_template_variadic.hpp:44:40: note:   expected a class template, got ‘BaseNoneTemplate’
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about adding another layer of generalization?

```
//...
template <typename... Types>
class VariadicTemplate;

// primary template class
template <template <typename...> class T_Self, typename... T_Params>
class VariadicTemplate<T_Self<T_Params...>, T_Params...>: public T_Self<T_Params...> {
//...
};

//...
void test_variadic_template(void) {
    VariadicTemplate<BaseNoneTemplate> non_template;
    VariadicTemplate<BaseTemplate<int>, int> an_template;
    non_template.print();
    an_template.print();
}
```

I've removed parts I didn't change. This code doesn't compile on MSVC2015, though for the reason unknown. I've filed a [bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2504633) but if you are using it then it won't help you any time soon.

---

This version works on MSVC(besides being more concise and clean):

```
template <typename... Types>
class VariadicTemplate;
//..
template <template <typename...> class T_Self, typename... T_Params>
class VariadicTemplate<T_Self<T_Params...>>: public T_Self<T_Params...> {
//...
}
//...
void test_variadic_template(void) {
    VariadicTemplate<BaseNoneTemplate> non_template;
    VariadicTemplate<BaseTemplate<int>> an_template;
    non_template.print();
    an_template.print();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, ixSci for giving me the answer.

Comment: Hi, ixSci. I pushed it previously and it turned to green. However you might not it was accepted. I push it again. Is it ok? Or how can I check it is working?

Answer (score 1):

If your `VariadicTemplate` expects `template <typename...> class, typename...` as template argument, you cannot specialize it for **type**.

What you can do is to expect **type** and specialize for specific type or (partial) specialize for types which come from template types.

```
template <typename T> class VariadicTemplate;

// Partial specialization
template <template <typename...> class C, typename... Ts>
class VariadicTemplate<C<Ts...>> : public C<Ts...> {
public:
    void print() { C<Ts...>::print(); };
    // or using C<Ts...>::print;
};

// Full specialization
template <>
class VariadicTemplate<BaseNoneTemplate> : public BaseNoneTemplate {
public:
    void print() { BaseNoneTemplate::print(); };
    // or using BaseNoneTemplate::print;
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f6408bff4a3b1c7e)

Comment: Thank you, Jarod42 for giving another solution. When I expect a template class only with a (template) type as template augment, that is, VariadicTemplate<a type>, your solution is more natural than my code above. Thank you again.